# Connect to a Switch with SSH and Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh

I need to connect to a Cisco Switch with SSH and Ruby. The problem I'm having is that the authentication is different. With PuTTY I do like this: enter the 'login as' (any value, no consistence) then it asks for 'User Name' and 'Password', like this screen:

[image: putty]

The option "SSH User Authentication by Password" in the switch config is disabled and enabling it is not an option.

My two last tries:

1 Using Net-SSH

```
Net::SSH.start(CISCO, USER) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec("echo hi")
end
```

Result: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

2 Using Net-SSH-Telnet

```
tn = Net::SSH::Telnet::new("Host" => CISCO,
"Timeout" => 60,
"Prompt" => /^\login as:/ )

tn.cmd("\n") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("#{USER}\n") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("#{PASS}\n") { |c| print c }
tn.print("echo oi") { |c| print c }
tn.close
```

Result: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

I guess I need to open a channel with the server and enter the login as, username and password as commands, but every time I get the AuthenticationFailed error. Any solution?

Comment: @ruba Is using an SSH key an option for authentication? Usually hardcoding a login and password is not the best option.

Comment: @user2276204 I cant enable this because I'm working with more than 3k switchs. I need to work with the default config =/

Comment: You can't compare how you'd do something using Putty or another SSH client, with using a library like Net::SSH. There is a lot of special-case code in apps like Putty, to deal with idiosyncrasies found in various SSH servers, and it's not in the underlying SSH library used by Net::SSH. Plus, from hard-won experience, we've found that Cisco's SSH implementation changes from device to device because of the OS differences. You'll need to add in an "Expect" capability also, because prompts change as you enable privileged modes.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices:

**Setup SSH keys**: This way is ideal because  it doesn't require a hard coded password. To do this you will need to generate the keys and edit your SSH config for password-less log in. Here is an example tutorial, [HOWTO: set up ssh keys](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/)

**Hardcoding your password**: You can achieve this by adding the password for your user in your SSH connection

Hardcoding example:

```
Net::SSH.start(CISCO, USER, :password => PASSWORD) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec("echo hi")
end
```

Comment: No idea, it seems it did not like the numbered list above the code. I was able to "fix" it by removing the list.