# Connect to a Cisco Switch with Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, telnet

[EDITED]

I'm trying to connect to a Cisco Switch and execute a few commands. My first try was with Net::SSH and I couldn't establish a channel. Second try was with plink and shell commands. Now I'm trying with Net::Telnet. This time at least I can connect to the switch.

The problem now is that it's executing only the first `telnet.cmd()`. To execute anything else I need to append some command at the end of the first `cmd()` (separated by `\n`). Here is my code:

```
telnet = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => CISCO,
                          "Timeout" => 10)
telnet.cmd("#{USER}\n#{PASS}") { |c| print c } #works fine
telnet.cmd("help") { |c| print c } #nothing happens
```

The second `cmd()` is not working. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why can't you use [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/) instead?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807355/ruby-broken-pipe-errnoepipe Broken pipe <Errno::EPIPE>

Comment: Actually, he can, check his [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404373/connect-to-a-switch-with-ssh-and-ruby) (I would not bother to answer again since never heard from him in this other)

Comment: @fotanus thanks for the help, but i gave up of using Net::SSH. I'm using Net::Telnet instead.

Comment: You can paste us the backtrace, and also add the output after run (for puts line)

Comment: I edited the question. I will not create separate questions anymore.

Comment: are you able to log in your router using ssh or telnet from the command line?

Comment: I have just know that only the test unit has telnet enabled. I will have to change everything to SSH again. Seems like this time the authentication will be with password, which turn things a bit easy. If I need further help I'll post here.